# Bash Environment Variable Issue

Tags: bash, environment-variables

We have a 3rd party scheduler that runs one of our job's shell scripts in bash.

When the shell script is called, it sets the environment variables from the scheduler as `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc on the command line.

Coming from our scheduler we have:

```
FILE_PATH1="/opt/shared/script1.sh"
FILE_PATH2="/opt/shared/script2.sh"
PROCESS_ID="SYNC1"
TYPE_RELN_IDS="520"
```

So, in our script I have:

```
export FILE_PATH1="$1"
export FILE_PATH2="$2"
...
export PROCESS_ID="${11}"
export TYPE_RELN_IDS="{$12}"
...
echo "PROCESS_ID =" $PROCESS_ID
echo "TYPE_RELN_IDS =" $TYPE_RELN_IDS
```

And for the shell script runtime output I am getting:

```
PROCESS_ID = SYNC1
TYPE_RELN_IDS = {/opt/shared/script1.sh}
```

instead of 520 for `TYPE_RELN_IDS`. Is there an issue with the 12th environment variable limit I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your dollar sign in the 12th variable is in the wrong place.

`export TYPE_RELN_IDS="{$12}"` should be `export TYPE_RELN_IDS="${12}"`

Comment: holy crap, dyslexia strikes again lol....thanks !!

Comment: Sure thing - no problem.